# Spring data JPA - concurrent access of Entity

Tags: concurrency, transactions, spring-data, locking, spring-data-jpa

I want to make sure that only 1 thread has access to an Entity in my service function. How to do that?

Example: I want to safely decrease count: even if multiple threads execute OrderService.remove(Product), I don't want 2 DB updates with the same counter value.

In a multithreaded environemnt 2 threads can execute this function at the same time, they may read the same counter value, and therefore update the DB with the same decreased value. This is undesirable.

Product:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private Integer count;

    ...
```

ProductService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService {

    public void remove(UUID productId) {

        final Product product = productRepository.findById(productId);

        // TODO how to lock product, so no other thread can modify it before this operation is committed?
        final Integer currentCount = product.getCount();
        product.setCount(currentCount-1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? You want thread-safe modifications to ` Product.count `  field or you want transactional database updates?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Updated the answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want you `remove(..)` method work **as a transaction** (so that there can't happen a **concurrent update to the Database** with this method). In order to do that, you should mark the method as `@Transactional`.
As long as **serializability** guarantees that the effect of concurrent transactions is equivalent to a serial (i.e. sequential) execution of them, setting isolation level explicitly to `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` is enough.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void remove(UUID productId) {
    ...
}
```

If you need more advance logic in dealing with transactions, you can use lower isolation levels and retry policy: `@Retryable(StaleStateException.class)`.
See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry for details.

Comment: What happens in case of conflicting transactions, if I don't specify the isolation level and no retry policy is set? Will only 1 transaction succeed?

Comment: The database will do all locking for you.     
If two transactions (your `remove()` methods) try to access the same data, one of them will be forced to wait until the other completes.  Those two transactions will be executed as it one of them was first, ant the other arrives after the first one was completed.

Comment: I understand this is the case if isolation=Isolation.SERLIALIZE is set, but what happens in case of a more relaxed isolation level? (e.g. the default one)

Comment: With other isolation levels you will get exactly what they guarantee to you. You can see this tutorial for example: https://techannotation.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/5-minutes-with-spring-transaction-isolation-level/

The behavior of default isolation level differ from database to database. For example, in Postgres it is Read Committed:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html